# How to read a simple CSV file with Datavec

Tags: csv, deeplearning4j, recordreader

I want to read a simple CSV file with just a list of numbers using Datavec, for use within Deeplearning4j.
I've tried numerous examples but keep getting errors.
e.g. when I execute this:

```
    RecordReader rrTest = new CSVRecordReader();
    rrTest.initialize(new FileSplit(new File(INPUT_FILE)));
    DataSetIterator testIter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(rrTest, 150, 0, 1);
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.nd4j.linalg.exception.ND4JIllegalStateException: Invalid shape: Requested INDArray shape [144, 0] contains dimension size values < 1 (all dimensions must be 1 or more).
```

Changing the 'labelIndex' from 0 to 1 gives the same error.

The data in the file looks like this:

```
112
118
132
129
121
135
148
148
136
119
104
118
115
```

How do I read this file? I guess the result should be a DataSet, as input for a dl4j.

Answer (score 0):

You have no labels. You need at least 2 values. The RecordReaderDataSetIterator usually expects there to be a label there somewhere. You haven't defined anything to learn. I'm not sure how new you are to machine learning, but I would step back and learn the basics first.